# How do I know which files will be included in a linux kernel before I build it?

Tags: linux, kernel, security, compiling

I am working on a project that includes building an old kernel version of linux.  This is fine, but I still need to patch the kernel of all previously found security vulnerabilities based on CVEs.  I have the CVEs and have extracted the names of the vulnerable files mentioned in them, along with the kernel versions it affects.

So far, I have found about 150 **potential** vulnerabilities that could affect my build, but obviously some of them affect files relevant to graphics drivers that I don't use.  So far, I have just gone through the list manually, checking if the files are included by using `make menuconfig`, and cating `Kconfig` in relevant folders.  This has worked alright so far, but these methods don't show the actual file names (e.g. ipc/sem.c) so it takes more work than necessary.

Ideally, I would like to somehow print a list of all the files that will be included in my build, and then just write a script to check if vulnerable files are included.

How can I find the names of ever source file (e.g. ipc/sem.c) that will be included in my build?

Comment: Migrating at the request of the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the build, then list the `.o` files. I think every `.c` or `.S` file that takes part in the build is compiled into a `.o` file with a corresponding name. This won't tell you if a security issue required a fix in a header file that's included in the build.

```
make vmlinux modules
find -name '*.o' -exec sh -c '
    for f; do for x in c S; do [ -e "${f%.o}.$x" ] && echo "${f%.o}.$x"; done; done
' _ {} +
```

A more precise method is to put the sources on a filesystem where access times are stored, and do the build. Files whose access time is not updated by the build were not used in this build.

```
touch start.stamp
make vmlinux modules
find -type f -anewer start.stamp
```